# Way to customize KeyManagerFactory in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Spring Boot version 2.1.1.RELEASE, I want to use netty's new `OpenSslCachingX509KeyManagerFactory` to reduce CPU consumption, but I don't see a proper way to set it. Reading the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/36c1c051b8106371d37f8a747cea0e369a8e5c84/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/netty/SslServerCustomizer.java#L97) seems it's hard coded.

Comment: You can extends from class `SslServerCustomizer`  and method `protected KeyManagerFactory getKeyManagerFactory` can be overwritten as you wish